# iphone 6s can't add to developer portal

Tags: ios, device

Is there any problem with iphone 6s when adding to developer portal. I tried to add several 6s phones, but those are doesn't recognize by the apple developer portal. And when try to install the app it does't allow to install. Is anybody know anything related to this?

Thank you

Comment: How are you obtaining the UDID?

Comment: I got from itunes and it gives me uppercase so I converted to lowercase and  added

Comment: Do you have updated xCode? What is the issue?

Comment: Can you show us what the format of the UDID you are using looks like? Maybe hash out a few characters for security reasons.

Comment: after I add the udid it doesnt recognize the phone model when I try to intall a build it doesnt allow me to install. but I addded 6+ it didnt give any issue

Comment: Might be problem with iOS version and XCode version, if not can you share your UDID by hashing some characters as @JoGoFo said, at least some people can understand the issue.

Comment: 7C556F0027##3CADD2D##DC7####F##418###4E0 here is it

Comment: And whats the connection with Xcode? I just add it from the developer site. my xcode is 7 beta